# Why aren't the web links clickable when viewing from mobile?

Tags: javascript, debugging, mobile, web

http://codepen.io/Amaltheya/pen/GrreVY

This is what I have so far. I am using mobile debug mode in Chrome to trouble shoot. I have also launched it to a server to make sure it's not just chrome being off. I'd appreciate any advice, or a fork if you think it's easy enough.

Just to restate the question clearly: Why won't the drop down menu links work when viewing from mobile inspect mode in Chrome?

The javascript that seems to be causing the issues:

```
//javascript for pixel art

let width, height;
let pixels = [];
let coloredPixels = [];
let colors = ['#540045', '#C60052', '#FF714B', '#EAFF87', '#ACFFE9'];
let currentPixel = 0;
const mousePosition = { x: window.innerWidth/2, y: window.innerHeight/2 };

const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const drawGrid = () => {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

  for (var i = 0, l = pixels.length; i < l; i++) {
    pixels[i][4] = 0;
  }

  for (var i = 0, l = coloredPixels.length; i < l; i++) {
    var pix = Math.floor(coloredPixels[i].y/10)*(Math.floor(width/10)+1) + Math.floor(coloredPixels[i].x/10);
    if (pixels[pix]) {
      pixels[pix][4] = coloredPixels[i].color;
      pixels[pix][5] = coloredPixels[i].alpha;
    }

    if (coloredPixels[i].alpha > 0) coloredPixels[i].alpha -= 0.008;
    if (coloredPixels[i].alpha < 0) coloredPixels[i].alpha = 0;
    coloredPixels[i].x += coloredPixels[i].vx;
    coloredPixels[i].y += coloredPixels[i].vy;
  }

  for (var i = 0, l = pixels.length; i < l; i++) {
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    ctx.fillStyle = '#222';
    ctx.fillRect(pixels[i][0], pixels[i][1], pixels[i][2], pixels[i][3]);
    ctx.globalAlpha = pixels[i][5];
    ctx.fillStyle = pixels[i][4];
    ctx.fillRect(pixels[i][0], pixels[i][1], pixels[i][2], pixels[i][3]);
  }
}

const resize = () => {
  width = window.innerWidth;
  height = window.innerHeight;
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  pixels = [];
  for (var y = 0; y < height/10; y++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < width/10; x++) {
      pixels.push([x*10, y*10, 8, 8, '#222', 1]);
    }
  }
}

const draw = () => {
  launchPixel();
  launchPixel();
  drawGrid();
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

const initColoredPixels = () => {
  for (var i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
    coloredPixels.push({
      x: width/2,
      y: height/2,
      alpha: 0,
      color: colors[i%5],
      vx: -1 + Math.random()*2,
      vy: -1 + Math.random()*2
    })
  }
}

const launchPixel = () => {
  coloredPixels[currentPixel].x = mousePosition.x;
  coloredPixels[currentPixel].y = mousePosition.y;
  coloredPixels[currentPixel].alpha = 1;

  currentPixel++;
  if (currentPixel > 299) currentPixel = 0;
}

resize();
initColoredPixels();
draw();

window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  mousePosition.x = e.pageX;
  mousePosition.y = e.pageY;
})

const touchMove = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  mousePosition.x = e.touches[0].pageX;
  mousePosition.y = e.touches[0].pageY;
}

document.addEventListener('touchstart', touchMove);
document.addEventListener('touchmove', touchMove);


// javascript for hamburger

$( document ).ready(function() {
  var hamburger = $('#hamburger-icon');

  hamburger.bind("mouseup", handleHam);
  hamburger.bind("touchend", handleHam);
});

function handleHam() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
     if($('.nav-menu').is(':hidden')){ // check to see if menu is hidden
         $('.nav-menu').slideDown();}  // if so slide down
     else{$('.nav-menu').slideUp();}   // else slide up


     return false;
}
```